# PayPal Sandbox RefundTransaction returns 10009 "You do not have a verified ACH"

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to set up programmatic refunds using the NVP RefundTransaction API in the PayPal Sandbox.

I'm using a modified version [of this PHP](https://www.kvcodes.com/2016/05/paypal-refund-transaction/) script to make my call. The API returns this error:

```
'L_ERRORCODE0' => string '10009'
'L_SHORTMESSAGE0' => string 'Transaction refused'
'L_LONGMESSAGE0' => string 'You do not have a verified ACH'
'L_SEVERITYCODE0' => string 'Error'
```

PayPal's [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/nvp-soap-api/errors/) for this code and error message says:

> This error occurs because you do not have sufficient funds in your
> PayPal balance to cover the amount of the refund and your PayPal
> account does not have an associated verified bank account. Be sure
> that you have sufficient funds in your PayPal balance and that you
> have verified the associated bank account.

However, the PayPal Sandbox account associated with the API credentials that I'm using has a "Bank Account" with an Account Number and Routing Number, and a PayPal "Balance" of 99999 GBP.

I don't know whether it's relevant to mention this, but "Payment Review" is set to OFF. Also, the request is being made in USD, but I've tried changing this GBP with no change in outcome.

My "Live" account has a balance of 0.0, and no associated bank account (at present). I don't see that this should matter, but I thought I'd mention it for completeness. I've double-checked that *I am* making the call to the Sandbox API and not the Live API.

Any ideas on what might be going wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirm the sandbox email address of the receiver account:

- Log into it and go to
  https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessprofile/settings/email
- You can resend a confirmation message from there if necessary.
- Read the notification via
  https://developer.paypal.com/developer/notifications/ , and sign in
  using the link provided to confirm the email

If this does not solve your problem, update your question with the full API error message, which should always include a correlation ID or debug_id among other things.

Comment: Thank you very much, I would never have considered the email address as an issue. This actually revealed a cascading set of problems. Firstly, the email address that I used for the Sandbox account doesn't exist - it points to a domain name that I control, but apparently I overlooked creating a matching mailbox. So I went to create one for it, and discovered that my domain host had somehow lost the MX entries for my email host. So that's been updated (on my behalf, in theory), so I'm not waiting for those updates to propagate. I'll come back once I've created the new mailbox.

Comment: The sandbox email only needs to be verified via Notifications. An actual mailbox account is not relevant and will never receive anything from sandbox.

Comment: Ah - pardon my ignorance. When I look at the email settings page, I'm not seeing an option to resend the confirmation (https://www.mediafire.com/convkey/2323/fnww932bffdnkpo6g.jpg). I did try adding another address earlier, and I see an entry for that in Notifications. But when I click on it, it seems to want to send an email to that address, and for me to type in a code. Unfortunately developer.paypal.com is returning "Sorry. We weren't able to process your request. Please try again in a little while." at the moment, so I'll have to return to that later. Thank you for your help

Comment: Well there's an edit button there. But if it is confirmed already, you will need to update your question with more information as I mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. When I press edit it says "We're sorry. You can't edit your primary email address." So I suppose it is already confirmed. I re-ran the API call again just now, this is a var_dump of the cURL response: 'TIMESTAMP' => string '2021-03-19T20:02:51Z', 'CORRELATIONID' => string 'd73d613241ac', 'ACK' => string 'Failure', 'VERSION' => string '94.0', 'BUILD' => string '55450593', 'L_ERRORCODE0' => string '10009', 'L_SHORTMESSAGE0' => string 'Transaction refused', 'L_LONGMESSAGE0' => string 'You do not have a verified ACH', 'L_SEVERITYCODE0' => string 'Error'

Comment: Perhaps the original transaction was in a different currency than your primary balance, and you don't have an open balance nor verified bank in the currency of the transaction you're attempting to refund.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. That is the case, the Sandbox account has "GB" as the "Profile" country, and under "Funding" the "PayPal Balance" is listed in GBP, while the amount I'm attempting to refund ("currencyCode") is "USD". However, if I change the currencyCode to "GBP" to match the Sandbox account, I receive an identical error (though a different CORRELATIONID, but this seems to be some kind of per-transaction code?).

Comment: I just tried changing the "refundType" to "Partial" instead of "Full", and the "currencyCode" to "GBP" instead of "USD", and I get a slightly different error: Still "10009", but the message is "The partial refund must be the same currency as the original transaction". Hmm. Does this mean that I must make sales in the same currency as my account - at least if I want to refund them. It seems strange that I would be able to make sales in a different currency (USD vs GBP) but that this would block refunds. I'll see what happens if I make a GBP sale, and then try a refund.

Comment: Open a USD balance instead of converting to GBP on receipt https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessmanage/account/money , then you will have something to refund USD transactions with.

Comment: Just wanted to follow up with a final note, at the URL you suggested above (https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessmanage/account/money), under "Currency Management" I clicked "Add a currency", and added US dollars. Then I hovered my mouse over the little icon next to my primary currency, selected "Convert currency" and transferred an amount to USD. Finally, I made USD my primary currency. Now when I attempt the refund, it completes successfully.

Comment: It shouldn't need to be the primary currency -- but other than that, sure.